# How to use Javascript Module Pattern with Knockout JS and Pager JS?

Tags: knockout.js, javascript, pagerjs

I want to use `Javascript Module Pattern` with `Knockout JS and Pager JS`, i know how to use `Javascript Module Pattern` and `Knockout JS and Pager JS` Separately but i don't know how to integrate them.Here is my code of `Javascript Module Pattern`

```
var Module = (function(){
    var my = {};

    my.testMethod = function(){
        alert("test method is called");
    };
    return my;
}());

(function(anyobj){

    anyobj.anotherMethod = function(){
        alert("another Method is called");
    };

    anyobj.testMethod();

}(Module));
```

now this code work find but i don't know how to integrate the above code with the given below code in order to make `knockout js and pager js` work fine with `Javascript Module Pattern`

```
var moduleViewModel = new Module();
pager.extendWithPage(moduleViewModel);
ko.applyBindings(moduleViewModel);
pager.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the following code with this one and this should work

```
var Module = (function(){
    var my = {};

    my.testMethod = function(){
        alert("test method is called");
    };
    return my;
}());

(function(anyobj){

    anyobj.anotherMethod = function(){
        alert("another Method is called");
    };

    anyobj.testMethod();

}(Module));

//---  Module is an Object so we can pass it to a function as an argument  ---//
 pager.extendWithPage(Module);
 ko.applyBindings(Module);
 pager.start();
```